# Updating HashMap values by reference replaces all values with the last updated value

Tags: java

Here is my code which passes a map to update the values. The products for all the value objects in the map is exactly the same which should not happen. The data is verified and I have different products for every case.

```java
public void mapCustomerData(Map<String, ExportDto> casesMap) {
  List<String> cins = new ArrayList<>(casesMap.keySet());
  populateProducts(casesMap, cins); 
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void populateProducts(Map<String, ExportDto> casesMap, List<String> cins) {
  try {
    List<ProductDto> products = service.retrieveProductsByCins(cins);
    // TODO: fix it
    casesMap.replaceAll((key, value) -> {
      value.setProducts(products.stream()
                    .filter(p -> equalsIgnoreCase(p.getCin(), key))
                    .collect(toList()));
      return value;
    });
  } catch (CustomerGenericException e) {
    log.error("some error msg", e);
  }
}
```

Attempt #2:

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void populateProducts(Map<String, ExportDto> casesMap, List<String> cins) {
  try {
    List<ProductDto> customerProducts = service.ProductDto(cins);
    casesMap.keySet().forEach(key -> casesMap.get(key).setProducts(products.stream()
                        .filter(p -> equalsIgnoreCase(p.getCin(), key))
                        .collect(toList())));

  } catch (CustomerGenericException e) {
    log.error("some error msg", e);
  }
}
```

Can anyone help with the same?

Comment: The problem isn't that clear. But did you mean to have `value.setProducts(value.getProducts().stream()...` instead of `value.setProducts(products.stream()...`?

Comment: Added some context. Basically i'm trying to populate products in `ExportDto` for every entry of the map.

However, all the values/ExportDtos are updated with the same products.

Comment: Did you see the second part of my comment? You're copying values from `products`, not filtering products on `value`.

Comment: hmm i don't get it. `products` is one large list of all products which is fetched beforehand. I'm just filtering the products on some criteria for every key of the map and setting the filtered products in the corresponding value of the map.

See: `.filter(p -> equalsIgnoreCase(p.getCin(), key))`

Answer (score 1):

The following code works as expected:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cin1 = "cin1";
    String cin2 = "cin2";
    String cin3 = "cin3";
    String cin4 = "cin4";
    String cin5 = "cin5";

    List<ProductDto> customerProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    customerProducts.add(new ProductDto(cin1));
    customerProducts.add(new ProductDto(cin2));
    customerProducts.add(new ProductDto(cin3));
    customerProducts.add(new ProductDto(cin4));
    customerProducts.add(new ProductDto(cin5));

    Map<String, ExportDto> casesMap = new HashMap<>();
    casesMap.put(cin1, new ExportDto());
    casesMap.put(cin2, new ExportDto());
    casesMap.put(cin3, new ExportDto());
    casesMap.put(cin4, new ExportDto());
    casesMap.put(cin5, new ExportDto());

    casesMap.keySet().forEach(key -> casesMap.get(key).setProducts(customerProducts.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getCin().equalsIgnoreCase(key))
            .collect(toList())));

    System.out.println(casesMap);
}
```

Which means that the following should also work:

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void populateProducts(Map<String, ExportDto> casesMap, List<String> cins) {
  try {
    List<ProductDto> customerProducts = service.ProductDto(cins);
    casesMap.keySet().forEach(key -> casesMap.get(key).setProducts(customerProducts.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getCin().equalsIgnoreCase(key))
            .collect(toList())));
  } catch (CustomerGenericException e) {
    log.error("some error msg", e);
  }
}
```

The only reason that could lead to the behaviour that you describe is if `casesMap` includes only references for the same `ExportDto` instance, as the following code proves:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cin1 = "cin1";
    String cin2 = "cin2";
    String cin3 = "cin3";
    String cin4 = "cin4";
    String cin5 = "cin5";

    List<ProductDto> customerProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    customerProducts.add(new ProductDto(cin1));
    customerProducts.add(new ProductDto(cin2));
    customerProducts.add(new ProductDto(cin3));
    customerProducts.add(new ProductDto(cin4));
    customerProducts.add(new ProductDto(cin5));

    Map<String, ExportDto> casesMap = new HashMap<>();
    ExportDto exportDto = new ExportDto();
    casesMap.put(cin1, exportDto);
    casesMap.put(cin2, exportDto);
    casesMap.put(cin3, exportDto);
    casesMap.put(cin4, exportDto);
    casesMap.put(cin5, exportDto);

    casesMap.keySet().forEach(key -> casesMap.get(key).setProducts(customerProducts.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getCin().equalsIgnoreCase(key))
            .collect(toList())));

    System.out.println(casesMap);
}
```

If this is the case, then you need to add a new constructor in `ExportDto` that accepts an `ExportDto` object, actually copying it:

```java
public class ExportDto {
    private List<ProductDto> products = new ArrayList<>();

    public ExportDto(ExportDto value) {
        this.products = new ArrayList<>(value.getProducts());
    }

    (...)
}
```

And then you can use `casesMap.forEach((key, value) -> casesMap.put(key, new ExportDto(value)));` to create the new `ExportDto`. This will fix it as the following shows:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cin1 = "cin1";
    String cin2 = "cin2";
    String cin3 = "cin3";
    String cin4 = "cin4";
    String cin5 = "cin5";

    List<ProductDto> customerProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    customerProducts.add(new ProductDto(cin1));
    customerProducts.add(new ProductDto(cin2));
    customerProducts.add(new ProductDto(cin3));
    customerProducts.add(new ProductDto(cin4));
    customerProducts.add(new ProductDto(cin5));

    Map<String, ExportDto> casesMap = new HashMap<>();
    ExportDto exportDto = new ExportDto();
    casesMap.put(cin1, exportDto);
    casesMap.put(cin2, exportDto);
    casesMap.put(cin3, exportDto);
    casesMap.put(cin4, exportDto);
    casesMap.put(cin5, exportDto);

    casesMap.forEach((key, value) -> casesMap.put(key, new ExportDto(value)));

    casesMap.keySet().forEach(key -> casesMap.get(key).setProducts(customerProducts.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getCin().equalsIgnoreCase(key))
            .collect(toList())));

    System.out.println(casesMap);
}
```

Comment: Wow i think the last part that you mentioned could be the culprit. It does contain references of ExitExportDto but whether all references are exactly the same is something I have to check. I’m quite sure that is the case. Any workaround for that?

Comment: Well, if that is the case you need to create a new instance of `ExportDto` for each of the entries in the Map, there is no other alternative. I've updated my answer with a way to fix this. Please check it ;)